# How to prove this problem about Connectivity.

Tags: general-topology

> problem:X and Y are topological space. $A \subsetneq X$,$B \subsetneq Y$,$X$ and $ Y$ are connected,then
> $ X×Y-A×B$ is connected.

I want to use difinition of connnectivity,to prove there no  extist a separation of $ X×Y-A×B$,but I didn't make it.Then i want to use some result about union of connect space to do it as like prove ' a finite product of  connected space is connected',but i don't know how to find connected space such that their union is  $ X×Y-A×B$.

Comment: Try this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214317/prove-that-x-times-y-setminus-a-times-b-is-connected

Comment: See also [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301095/a-product-of-connected-spaces-minus-a-product-of-proper-subsets-of-both).